# Why does google cloud converse_conversation returns None or empty?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working with google cloud discoveryengine_v1 using flask and I'm trying to request a new conversation.

I've got the sample code from the documentation [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/main/packages/google-cloud-discoveryengine/samples) but upon testing it returns a type error that says the function doesn't return anything.

Code below:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from google.cloud import discoveryengine_v1

@app.route("/new", methods=['POST'])
def new_question():
   api_data = request.get_json()

   answer_response = sample_converse_conversation(api_data['question']) # api_data['question'] is a string

   print(answer_response)
   return answer_response

def sample_converse_conversation(question):
   try:
      # Create a client
      client = discoveryengine_v1.ConversationalSearchServiceClient()

      # Initialize request argument(s)
      request = discoveryengine_v1.ConverseConversationRequest(
        name="<name value>", # removed the value but this has the project details 
      )

      # Make the request
      response = client.converse_conversation(request=request)

      # Handle the response
      return response
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

Error below:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1478, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1458, in wsgi_app
  response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
  return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
  return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
  return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\decorator.py", line 130, in wrapped_function
  resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 175, in make_response
  return current_app.make_response(args)  # type: ignore
File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1161, in make_response
  raise TypeError( TypeError: The view function for 'new_question' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

My backend directory:

[image]

For testing I'm using postman to run the API request.

Comment: What output do you see from `print(answer_response)` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon This: 

raise TypeError( TypeError: The view function for 'new_question' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Comment: That cannot be the output from the print statement, because the print is **before** the function would return.

Comment: @JohnGordon my bad i got confused. it prints out None

Comment: Well, then that is the reason.  The function **did** return None, exactly as the error says.  `answer_response` is None, and that is the variable that the function returns, so the function returned None.

Comment: It seems you expected the `sample_converse_conversation()` function to return something other than None.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reviewing the documentation thoroughly, the value assigned to attribute name was missing a (-) at the end.

```
projects/{project_number}/locations/{location_id}/collections/{collection}/dataStores/{data_store_id}/conversations/{conversation_id}. Use projects/{project_number}/locations/{location_id}/collections/{collection}/dataStores/{data_store_id}/conversations/-
```

Adding this here if anyone encounters the same haha!